# cannot open <resnet-18.t7> in mode r while trying to train SeGAN model

Tags: deep-learning, lua, mode, resnet

I am trying to implement the SeGAN paper with the repository [here](https://github.com/ehsanik/SeGAN). I installed the prerequisite and tried to train the model with:

```
th main.lua -baseLR 1e-3 -end2end -istrain "train"
```

and I got this error:

```
WARNING: specified initialized model is ignored because resnet model will be loaded!    
/home/darya/distro/install/bin/luajit: cannot open <resnet-18.t7> in mode r  at /home/darya/distro/pkg/torch/lib/TH/THDiskFile.c:673
stack traceback:
    [C]: at 0x7f6f3df5e210
    [C]: in function 'DiskFile'
    /home/darya/distro/install/share/lua/5.1/torch/File.lua:405: in function 'load'
    /home/darya/SeGAN/networks/ModelTrainTestBatch.lua:285: in function 'LoadModel'
    main.lua:293: in main chunk
    [C]: in function 'dofile'
    ...rya/distro/install/lib/luarocks/rocks/trepl/scm-1/bin/th:150: in main chunk
    [C]: at 0x55fcae37f570
```

I'm not sure (since I'm not experinced) but I assume resnet is stopping another model to be loaded but it can't load due to some problem either. I've searched about it and couldn't find something helpful for my problem.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: does the file exist? the error says this file is not readable. do you have permissions to read this file? this is not related to Lua

Comment: compare this vs your setup https://github.com/ehsanik/SeGAN/search?q=resnet_path  you're trying to load a file at config.resnet_path. make sure there is a file